How to use ShellExecuteEx in windows registry?
I want to add a context menu entry which will start a program elevated with admin privileges using the runas verb of ShellExecuteEx. I know how to add the context menu entry and registry command, thus making the entry start the program but I don't know how to use ShellExecuteEx to start the program with the runas verb.
I know I can create a shortcut and set "Run as administrator" in the properties but that is not what I want to do, thank you!
